# Cómo solventar este error en tiempo de ejecución en java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

estoy realizando un problema que me piden que introduzca la fecha en un formato numérico(DD/MM/AAAA) o un formato alfanumérico(Abril 23, 2021) , y de acuerdo con la elección de un formato u otro, transformar al formato contrario. Cuando ejecuto el código y escogo la opción dos en introduzco los datos correspondientes aparece este error:

Introduzca 1 para colocar la fecha en formato numérico, y 2 para colocarlo en formato alfanumérico: 2

Formato alfanumérico(Escribir solo el mes con palabras y debe comenzar en mayúscula).

Introduzca el día: 12

Introduzca el mes: Julio

Introduzca el año: 14

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at Fecha.formatoNumérico(Fecha.java:29)
at Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

Y aquí están los códigos:

```
public class Fecha
{
    //Atributos
    private int día;
    private int mes;
    private int año;
    private String mesAlfanumérico;

    //Métodos constructores
    public Fecha( int día, int mes, int año )
    {
        this.día = día;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.año = año;
    }
     
    public Fecha( String mesAlfanumérico, int día, int año )
    {
        this.mesAlfanumérico = mesAlfanumérico;
        this.día = día;
        this.año = año;
    }

    //Métodos 
    public void formatoNumérico()
    {
        int mes = 0;

        switch( mesAlfanumérico )
        {
            case "Enero" :
                mes = 1;
                break;
            case "Febrero" :
                mes = 2;
                break;
            case "Marzo" :
                mes = 3;
                break;
            case "Abril" :
                mes = 4;
                break;
            case "Mayo" :
                mes = 5;
                break;
            case "Junio" :
                mes = 6;
                break;
            case "Julio" :
                mes = 7;
                break;
            case "Agosto" :
                mes = 8;
                break;
            case "Septiembre" :
                mes = 9;
                break;
            case "Octubre" :
                mes = 10;
                break;
            case "Noviembre" :
                mes = 11;
                break;
            default :
                mes = 12;
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(día+"/"+mes+"/"+año);
    }
    
    public void formatoAlfanumérico()
    {
        String mesAlfanumérico;

        switch( mes )
        {
            case 1 :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Enero";
                break;
            case 2 :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Febrero";
                break;
            case 3 :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Marzo";
                break;
            case 4 :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Abril";
                break;
            case 5 :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Mayo";
                break;
            case 6 :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Junio";
                break;
            case 7 :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Julio";
                break;
            case 8 :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Agosto";
                break;
            case 9 :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Septiembre";
                break;
            case 10 :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Octubre";
                break;
            case 11 :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Noviembre";
                break;
            default :
                mesAlfanumérico = "Diciembre";
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(mesAlfanumérico+" "+día+", "+año);

    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        int día = 0;
        int mes = 0;
        int año = 0;
        String mesAlfanumérico; 

        System.out.print("Introduzca 1 para colocar la fecha en formato numérico, y 2 para colocarlo en formato alfanumérico: ");
        int opción = leer.nextInt();

        while( opción != 1 && opción != 2 )     
        {
            System.out.print("Error, introduzca un valor dentro del rango correspondiente (1-2): ");
            opción = leer.nextInt();
        }

        if( opción == 1 )
        {
            System.out.println("Formato númerico(Escribir todo en números).");
            System.out.print("Introduzca el día: ");
            día = leer.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Introduzca el mes: ");
            mes = leer.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Introduzca el año: ");
            año = leer.nextInt();

            Fecha f1 = new Fecha( día, mes, año );

            f1.formatoAlfanumérico();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Formato alfanumérico(Escribir solo el mes con palabras y debe comenzar en mayúscula).");

            System.out.print("Introduzca el día: ");
            día = leer.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Introduzca el mes: ");
            mesAlfanumérico = leer.next();
            System.out.print("Introduzca el año: ");
            año = leer.nextInt();

            Fecha f1 = new Fecha( mesAlfanumérico, día, año );

            f1.formatoNumérico();
        }
    }
}
```

¿Por que en tiempo de ejecución si ambos están en el mismo tipo de dato, por que me aparece ese error ?

Comment: Lo probé en ambos formatos y funcionó bien.

Comment: Solo construye nuevamente tu proyecto, no tiene ningùn error.

Comment: Funciona! solo como recomendación cambia el while por un if

Answer (score 0):

No deberías poner la línea que dice f1.formatoNumerico dentro del While(opcion==1)? digo porque creo que están al revés.
y el que dice f1.formatoAlfanumerico no deberia ir dentro del Else?
tal que asi:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        int día = 0;
        int mes = 0;
        int año = 0;
        String mesAlfanumérico; 

        System.out.print("Introduzca 1 para colocar la fecha en formato numérico, y 2 para colocarlo en formato alfanumérico: ");
        int opción = leer.nextInt();

        while( opción != 1 && opción != 2 )     
        {
            System.out.print("Error, introduzca un valor dentro del rango correspondiente (1-2): ");
            opción = leer.nextInt();
        }

        if( opción == 1 )
        {
            System.out.println("Formato númerico(Escribir todo en números).");
            System.out.print("Introduzca el día: ");
            día = leer.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Introduzca el mes: ");
            mes = leer.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Introduzca el año: ");
            año = leer.nextInt();

            Fecha f1 = new Fecha( día, mes, año );

            f1.formatoNumérico();

        }else{
            System.out.println("Formato alfanumérico(Escribir solo el mes con palabras y debe comenzar en mayúscula).");

            System.out.print("Introduzca el día: ");
            día = leer.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Introduzca el mes: ");
            mesAlfanumérico = leer.next();
            System.out.print("Introduzca el año: ");
            año = leer.nextInt();

            Fecha f1 = new Fecha( mesAlfanumérico, día, año );

            f1.formatoAlfanumérico();
            
        }
    }
}
```